# Get filenotfoundexception using RadAsyncUpload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

i use the Telerik radasyncupload control like this:

Web.Config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Telerik.AsyncUpload.TemporaryFolder" value="~/App_Data/RadUploadTemp" />
</appSettings>
```

ASP.NET

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="rauIconUpload" runat="server" ChunkSize="0" Localization-Cancel="Löschen" Localization-Remove="Entfernen" Localization-Select="Auswählen"
  Culture="de-DE" Skin="MetroTouch" TargetFolder="img/icons" MaxFileInputsCount="1">
</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
<telerik:RadButton ID="rbtnIconUpload" runat="server" Text="Speichern" Skin="MetroTouch"></telerik:RadButton>
```

VB.NET

```
Private Sub rbtnIconUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbtnIconUpload.Click

    If rtxtIconBezeichnung.Text = String.Empty Or rtxtIconBezeichnung.Text = Nothing Or CHKValidation(rtxtIconBezeichnung.Text) = False Then
        rnfUngueltigeEingabe.Visible = True
    Else
        Try
            For Each f As UploadedFile In rauIconUpload.UploadedFiles
                Dim img As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(f.InputStream)
                Dim h As Integer = img.Height
                Dim w As Integer = img.Width
                img.Dispose()

                Dim fileName As String = f.GetName()
                IconPfad = "~/img/icons/" & fileName

                If w = 16 And h = 16 Then
                    IconSize = "16x16"
                ElseIf w = 32 And h = 32 Then
                    IconSize = "32x32"
                Else
                    rnfIconNichtErzeugt.Visible = True
                    Exit For
                End If

                IconErzeugt = Datenzugriff.CRTNeuesIcon(rtxtIconBezeichnung.Text, IconPfad, rcbIconGruppe.SelectedValue, IconSize)
                If IconErzeugt = True Then
                    rnfIconErzeugt.Visible = True
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock([GetType](), "CloseScript", "redirectParentPage('IconVerwaltung.aspx')", True)
                Else
                    rnfIconNichtErzeugt.Visible = True
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            rnfIconNichtErzeugt.Visible = True
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

If i try to use InputStream i get a filenotfoundexeption. I added a Screanshot of this error.

So, does someone have a idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you for reading. 
Daniel

[image: filenotfound]

Comment: Does the user being used to run the application have permission to write files to this folder? Have you looked in the temporary folder to check whether the file exists at the point the exception is thrown?

Comment: The User has permission and the file exists the whole time in temporary folder. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the TargetFolder property from the markup:

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="rauIconUpload" runat="server" ChunkSize="0" Localization-Cancel="Löschen" Localization-Remove="Entfernen" Localization-Select="Auswählen"
  Culture="de-DE" Skin="MetroTouch" MaxFileInputsCount="1">
</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

and save the file manually from in the click button event.